# How to prevent a package from being installed

Tags: package-management, chromium

For personal reasons, I want to prevent chrome/chromium from ever being installed on my computer.

I'm looking for something as extreme as locking it down with a password and then throwing away that password. That would ensure I'm never going to get it installed.
Obviously I could do that with my root password, but lets be serious :P I need that password for other things too

Comment: But that's exactly the problem. I want to prevent myself from installing chrome. My self control is non-existent right now and I need to implement some drastic measures until I learn how to get it back

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to make a dummy chrome/chromium package and give it an absurdly high version number. Then you install the dummy package, and in the future whenever something tries to install chrome it'll be prevented because you have a "newer" version of chrome installed. I can't remember how to do this off the top of my head so you'll have to research it yourself or wait for someone else to help you.

Comment: Legend, will do both this and tumbleweeds answer. Also why the downvote :(

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green. This means "[yes, this answer is correct](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)"! **;-)**

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with [APT pinning](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt_preferences).

Create `/etc/apt/preferences.d/we-hate-chromium` with the contents:

```
Package: chromium
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1
```

A negative priority causes the package to never be installed by APT. (It can still be installed directly with `dpkg`, though.